Continuity and uniform continuity on products
Let $X,Y,Z$ be metric spaces, and $F:X \times Y \rightarrow Z$ be a continuous function. Further, suppose that for each $x \in X, F_x: Y \rightarrow Z$ is uniformly continuous. Then, is the canonical map $\tilde{F}: X \times \overline{Y} \rightarrow \overline{Z}$ also continuous?
A proof or a counterexamle would be appreciated. I do see continuity if $F$ were separately uniformly continuous in both variables.

No. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $Y = (0, 1]$, and $Z = \mathbb{R}$. Let $F(x, y) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2}$. Then $F$ satisfies all the requisite conditions. But its extension $\tilde{F}: \mathbb{R} \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by,
$$\tilde{F}(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} &, \, \text{if} \, x \neq 0\\ 0 &, \, \text{if} \, x = 0\end{cases}$$
Which is not continuous at $(0, 0)$.

Nice! The $F_y$'s are also uniformly continuous right? I think separate uniform continuity just doesn't work, you need uniform continuity on the product.

@Anupam Yes. Both $F_y$ and $F_x$ are uniformly continuous in this example.
